# How do I call function methods in Linq to Entity Framework and keep pagination?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, pagination

I need to transform some paginated data from Linq to Entity Framework.
The data should be displayed in MVC Contrib Grid / Pager, so it needs to be paginated and the backend SQL Server should paginate the data.

So I have this code as a working base:

```
MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
IQueryable<HighScore> highscores = db.HighScores.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
return View(highscores.AsPagination(page.GetValueOrDefault(1), 10));
```

This generates a pretty paged SQL query with `SELECT TOP (10) ... WHERE rownum ETC..`
Great, backend SQL Server pagination, the way it should be.

So now I need to transform my entities to a little bit different model.

```
private HighScoreModel GetUrlForImage(string userId, int? score, bool isAnonymous)
{
  return new HighScoreModel
  {
    // transformation, left out for simplicity
  };
}
```

I can't simply do:

```
var fixedData = from v in highscores
                select GetUrlForImage(v.UserId, v.Score, v.IsAnonymous);
```

because that will get me (expected): 
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'MvcContribTest.Models.HighScoreModel GetUrlForImage(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

So I need `ToList()` the entities in order to call my translation method, something like this:

```
var fixedData = from v in highscores.ToList()
                select GetUrlForImage(v.UserId,v.Score,v.IsAnonymous);
```

Which technically now works, but I have lost the backend SQL Server pagination because the `ToList()` conversion from `IQueryable()`.

How can I do a server side pagination in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about applying pagination before the ToList then do the transformation:

```
var fixedData = from v in highscores.AsPagination(page.GetValueOrDefault(1), 10).ToList()
                select GetUrlForImage(v.UserId,v.Score,v.IsAnonymous);
```

EDIT: To use with the MVC Contrib grid you will need to wrap it up with the `CustomPagination<T>` class this is [built in](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8378504d4571#src/MVCContrib/Pagination/CustomPagination.cs) in MVC Contrib:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
  var itemsPerPage = 5;
  var db = new MyEntities();
  var totalItems = db.HighScores.Count();

  IQueryable<HighScore> highscores = db.HighScores.OrderBy(highscore => highscore.ID);
  var pagedData = from highscore in highscores.AsPagination(page.GetValueOrDefault(1), itemsPerPage).ToList()
                  select highscore;

  var transformedData = new CustomPagination<HighScoreModel>(pagedData.Select(highscore => TransformData(highscore)), 
                                                             page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1, 
                                                             itemsPerPage,
                                                             totalItems);
  return View(transformedData);
}
```

Comment: Well, the MVC Grid/Pager expects a Paginated<> collection, and if I add pagination to the (Enumerable) fixedData in your solution, pagination doesn't work at all.

Comment: hmmm.. not sure about the syntax you are proposing there.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson I've cleaned the sample code and also added a link for the `CustomPagination` class.

Comment: Thanks for getting my eyes on the CustomPagination class, that will work. I hesitated to mark your answer as correct since your code was very inomplete. 1) Linq statement missing select, 2) The pagedData collection doesn't have the Pagenumber, Page and TotalItems properties. (how could it?) 3) One cant' use the itemcount of the paged data, it will always return pagesize. (One has to determine the total numitems in the table in advance). I have cleaned up your suggestion with something that resembles working code. In any case, this works now.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson Thanks for the clean up :) It was late and it was early and I haven't tried to compile it.